# Row in listview not preserve the makeover and appears repeated

Tags: android, listview

I have a list that when you click on the row on the right side the layout with the icon is changed by other. This makes it well but when I scrolling in the list, I notice there are rows with the same icon without do click. Also, if I scroll quickly these same icons are lost and are built differently. I think it's on the reuse of cells but I can not find the solution. What I want is that the image stays active only in the row where clicka.

Thanks!!

**`Adapter` class:**

```
public class ListadoVotantesArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Votante> {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<Votante> listaVotantes;
    private int rowLayout;
    private View mConverView;

    public ListadoVotantesArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Votante> objects) {
        super(context, resource,objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.listaVotantes = objects;
        this.rowLayout = resource;
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return this.listaVotantes.size();
    }

    public Votante getVotante(int position){
        return this.listaVotantes.get(position);
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView lblName;
        public TextView lblLastName;
        public TextView lblDni;
        public TextView lblVoterNumber;
        public RelativeLayout lytVoted;
        public RelativeLayout lytCanVote;
        public RelativeLayout lytUndo;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View converView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        mConverView = converView;
        if (mConverView == null){
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            this.mConverView = inflater.inflate(this.rowLayout, parent, false);

            if (mConverView != null){
                viewHolder.lblName = (TextView) mConverView.findViewById(R.id.lblVoterName);
                viewHolder.lblLastName = (TextView) mConverView.findViewById(R.id.lblVoterLastName);
                viewHolder.lblDni = (TextView) mConverView.findViewById(R.id.lblDni);
                viewHolder.lblVoterNumber = (TextView) mConverView.findViewById(R.id.lblNumber);
                viewHolder.lytVoted = (RelativeLayout) mConverView.findViewById(R.id.lytVoted);
                viewHolder.lytCanVote = (RelativeLayout) mConverView.findViewById(R.id.lytCanVote);
                viewHolder.lytUndo = (RelativeLayout) mConverView.findViewById(R.id.lytUndo);
                mConverView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) mConverView.getTag();
        }

        Votante votante = getVotante(position);

        viewHolder.lblName.setText(votante.getNombre());
        viewHolder.lblLastName.setText(votante.getApellidos());
        viewHolder.lblDni.setText(votante.getDni());
        viewHolder.lblVoterNumber.setText(""+votante.getNumVotante());

        if (votante.getVotado()){
            viewHolder.lytVoted.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.lytCanVote.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
            viewHolder.lytVoted.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.lytCanVote.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        mConverView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewHolder.lytUndo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return mConverView;
    }
}
```

**Layout Row:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lyt_voter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="1dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lytVoterNumber"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@color/lightBlueItemList">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="1999"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lytVoterData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/lytCanVote"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lytVoterNumber"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/lytCanVote"
        android:background="@color/whiteItemList"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblVoterLastName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Suarez Garcia de la Serna"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblVoterName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="José Carlos"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblDni"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="44950962S"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lytCanVote"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/yellowItemList"
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        android:minWidth="30dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgVote"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/flecha" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lytVoted"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/grrenAcceptList"
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        android:minWidth="30dp"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgAccept"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/aceptar"
             />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        android:minWidth="30dp"
        android:background="@color/redD3"
        android:id="@+id/lytUndo"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imgUndo"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/undo"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow below Idea

1) this line of code `mConverView = converView;` doesn't makes sense. directly use `converView(View from getView param).` Remove `mConvertView` from the adapter.

2) Add some mechanism which can tell you which row is clicked and save that variable.

Example:- Have an boolean Array of size Rows.size . and set them in onClick.

```
Boolean[] array = new Boolean[getSize()];
```

in onClick that you already have in your getview set this.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
     array[position] = !array[position];
     viewHolder.lytUndo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     //You do not need to call notifyDatasetChange.
```

3) in `getView()`, when you are setting data in to row items/or just before `onClick`. have a check like below.

```
if(array[position])// this will tell you if you need to show or hid lytUndo thing
     viewHolder.lytUndo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // Show it
else 
     viewHolder.lytUndo.setVisibility(View.GONE); // hide it or do whatever you want
```

**You might need to set some params as final**

I have written this as simple as possible, comment back with your result.